# How to save an Image using URL in python/django

Tags: python, django, file-io

If you were to save an Image using it's URL how would you do it ?

Also how do I give the Image a unique file name while saving it.

```
    response = urllib.urlopen(image_url)
    file_name = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for x in range(10))
    f = open('/media/images/temp/'+file_name, "wb")
    f.write(response.read())
    f.close()
```

It throws no error nor saves the file... I'm new to this I have no clue what is going wrong : |

Comment: This question is quite vague. If you have a URL of an image, simply fetch it using `wget` (or urllib if within Python). Why don't you *try* doing it and then post back with problems you're facing?

Comment: If working on it since 4 hours doesn't qualify as trying I don't know what will.

Comment: I'll post what I have coded....please do help

Comment: Guys! finally a new error - [Errno ftp error] [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connectio failed because connected host has failed to respond. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import urllib
import string
import random
import os

filename_charset = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
filename_length = 10
file_save_dir = '/home/user/download/'

filename = ''.join(random.choice(filename_charset)
                   for s in range(filename_length))

urllib.urlretrieve ("http://www.example.com/image.png", 
                    os.path.join(file_save_dir, filename + '.png'))
```

Comment: finally a new error - [Errno ftp error] [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connectio failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: The URL is an example. If you want someone to code up a complete program for you, you should perhaps consider hiring someone to do so.

Comment: It gives different errors for different URLs man... I don't know what to do.

Comment: I have just successfully retrieved Google's logo from http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png  But Zach, there are no oracles here to guess, what are you trying to retrieve and which kind of errors you get. Any details on "different errors"?

Comment: Besides I've posted the question to learn what I'm doing wrong. Isn't that what StackOverflow's about ? 
I respect you guys for answering my queries so many times...it would be an understatement to say that you saved my life a couple of times too.
But I detest how you discourage my curiosity. It's a shame.

Comment: It seems the problem was that the site I was scraping had set relative paths in their src atrribrutes for their img html tags.

Comment: Zach, just in case that the site you're scraping is not http://www.cia.gov or similar, can you paste an example url here?